# Unable to pass result of one command as argument to another

Tags: macros, fp

In my document I have the need to do a little bit of maths, which is related to sizing images. Specifically I need a linear interpolation function, the inverse function of linear interpolation, and a clamping function.

I have constructed these functions, as well as a document to test them:

```
\documentclass[twoside]{memoir}
\usepackage[papersize={8.5in,11in}, vmargin=0.5in, outer=1in, inner=0.5in, includehead, includefoot]{geometry}
\usepackage{fp}

\makeatletter

\newcommand\clamp[3] {
    \def\clamped{#1}
    \ifdim #1pt>#3pt
        \def\clamped{#3}
    \fi
    \ifdim #1pt<#2pt
        \def\clamped{#2}
    \fi
    \clamped
}

\newcommand\unlerp[3] {
    \FPsub\numerator{\number #1}{\number #2}
    \FPsub\denominator{\number #3}{\number #2}
    \FPdiv\result{\numerator}{\denominator}
    \result
}

\newcommand\lerp[3] {
    \FPsub\result{\number #3}{\number #2}
    \FPmul\result{\number #1}{\result}
    \FPadd\result{\number\numexpr #2}{\result}
    \result
}

\makeatother

\begin{document}

\huge

\bfseries Clamp Tests
\normalfont

Clamp -5 between 0 and 100: \clamp{-5}{0}{100}

Clamp 45 between 0 and 100: \clamp{45}{0}{100}

Clamp 150 between 0 and 100: \clamp{150}{0}{100}

Clamp -0.5 between 0 and 1: \clamp{-0.5}{0}{1}

Clamp 0.5 between 0 and 1: \clamp{0.5}{0}{1}

Clamp 1.5 between 0 and 1: \clamp{1.5}{0}{1}

\bfseries Lerp Tests
\normalfont

Lerp 0 between 0 and 100: \lerp{0}{0}{100}

Lerp 0.5 between 0 and 100: \lerp{0.5}{0}{100}

Lerp 1 between 0 and 100: \lerp{1}{0}{100}

\bfseries Unlerp Tests
\normalfont

Unlerp 0 between 0 and 100: \unlerp{0}{0}{100}

Unlerp 45 between 0 and 100: \unlerp{45}{0}{100}

Unlerp 150 between 0 and 100: \unlerp{100}{0}{100}

Unlerp 0.5 between 0 and 2: \unlerp{0.5}{0}{2}

\bfseries Combination Tests
\normalfont

Store manual value in variable: \def\testa{0.500000000000000000}

Use manual variable in clamp: \clamp{\testa}{0}{1}

Store unlerp result in variable: \def\testb{\unlerp{50}{0}{100}}

Output unlerp result variable: \testb

%Variable -> clamp: \clamp{\testb}{0}{1}
% Fails with the following error messages:
%  ! Missing number, treated as zero.
%  ! Illegal unit of measure (pt inserted).
%  ! Missing = inserted for \ifdim.

%Unlerp -> Clamp: \clamp{\unlerp{50}{0}{100}}{0}{1}
% Fails with the following error messages:
%  ! Missing number, treated as zero.
%  ! Illegal unit of measure (pt inserted).
%  ! Missing = inserted for \ifdim.

\end{document}
```

[image: Screenshot]

In isolation they seem to work, but I'm having difficulty combining them. If I try to call them by nesting their arguments I get an error. I can store the output of one using `\def` and then display it on the page, but as soon as I try to pass it to the next command I get the same error. The failing calls can be seen at the bottom of my example, commented out.

The error I receive is:

```
Missing number, treated as zero.

Illegal unit of measure (pt inserted).

Missing = inserted for \ifdim.
```

(Plus a bunch more error messages that are repetitions of the above)

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I would suggest using `fp`-commands from the upcoming `LaTeX3`-project, not to be confused with the package `fp` you are using. The `fp`-package is old and clunky.

The following uses the syntax from the `LaTeX3`-project, or `expl3`, which is meant for package and class writers. Therefore, it might seem a bit more cryptic, but it has some very nice advantages. In the code below, I've made the macro `\fpeval` available for use with the regular latex-syntax, for easier input, so you don't have to learn anything about the new syntax at all. Just use `\fpeval{equation}` like a normal `LaTeX`-macro.

With it, you can do lots of calculations with easier input than compared to the package `fp`. Especially see how much shorter and easier to read the new macros become. There are many mathematical functions available, I've added a few of them as an example at the bottom.

You can find more information about the available functions and their usage in *Part XXII
The l3fp package: floating points* of *interface3* documentation.

Note that you can always locate the documentation using the command-line/terminal by writing `texdoc interface3`, and that works for any package. The documentation is also available at http://ctan.org/pkg/interface3

#### The error

The error is due to expansions. *Josephs Wright's* answer here gives a great explanation and for why the original code doesn't work.

Defining your macros with `xparse` seems to fix this.

#### Edit:

I've removed the `\fp_compare` as `fpeval` has `max(1,2,3)` and `min(1,2,3)` functions available, which outputs the largest and smallest respectivily.

I also took the advice from *egreg* and made the macros expandable.

#### Output

[image]

#### Code

```
\documentclass[twoside]{memoir}
\usepackage[
  papersize={8.5in,11in},
  vmargin=0.5in,
  outer=1in,
  inner=0.5in,
  includehead,
  includefoot,
  ]{geometry}
\usepackage{xparse}


\ExplSyntaxOn  % enable LaTeX3-syntax
% If you don't want to use syntax from LaTeX3 in your code, we can make them
% available as regular LaTeX-syntax by the following commands:
  \cs_set_eq:NN \fpeval \fp_eval:n % Make fpeval available. Create a Control Sequence(macro) named  `\fpeval`, and  Set it Equal to LaTeX3-macro `\fp_eval`.
\ExplSyntaxOff % disable LaTeX3-syntax

\DeclareExpandableDocumentCommand{\clamp}{ m m m }{% Make a expandable macro,
    % with 3 Mandatory arguments
  \fpeval{min(max(#1,#2),#3)}
}

\DeclareExpandableDocumentCommand{\unlerp}{ m m m }{% Make a expandable macro,
    % with 3 Mandatory arguments
  \fpeval{ ( #1 - #2 ) / ( #3 - #2 ) }%
}

\DeclareExpandableDocumentCommand{\lerp}{ m m m }{% Make a expandable macro,
    %with 3 Mandatory arguments
    \fpeval{ ( #3 - #2 ) * #1 + #2 }%
}


\begin{document}

\huge

\bfseries Clamp Tests
\normalfont

Clamp -5 between 0 and 100: \clamp{-5}{0}{100}

Clamp 45 between 0 and 100: \clamp{45}{0}{100}

Clamp 150 between 0 and 100: \clamp{150}{0}{100}

Clamp -0.5 between 0 and 1: \clamp{-0.5}{0}{1}

Clamp 0.5 between 0 and 1: \clamp{0.5}{0}{1}

Clamp 1.5 between 0 and 1: \clamp{1.5}{0}{1}

\bfseries Lerp Tests
\normalfont

Lerp 0 between 0 and 100: \lerp{0}{0}{100}

Lerp 0.5 between 0 and 100: \lerp{0.5}{0}{100}

Lerp 1 between 0 and 100: \lerp{1}{0}{100}

\bfseries Unlerp Tests
\normalfont

Unlerp 0 between 0 and 100: \unlerp{0}{0}{100}

Unlerp 45 between 0 and 100: \unlerp{45}{0}{100}

Unlerp 150 between 0 and 100: \unlerp{100}{0}{100}

Unlerp 0.5 between 0 and 2: \unlerp{0.5}{0}{2}

\bfseries Combination Tests
\normalfont

Store manual value in variable: \def\testa{0.5}

Use manual variable in clamp: \clamp{\testa}{0}{1}

Store unlerp result in variable: \def\testb{\unlerp{50}{0}{100}}

Output unlerp result variable: \testb\

Variable \(\rightarrow\) clamp: \clamp{\testb}{0}{1}

\textbf{Easy calculations, just as an example:}

\verb|\fpeval{pi * 4^2 }| :
      \fpeval{pi * 4^2 }

\verb|\fpeval{asind(\testb)}| :
      \fpeval{asind(\testb)}

\end{document}
```

Comment: "I would suggest using fp-commands from the upcoming LaTeX3-project." I'm pretty new to LaTeX. Are you saying there's a way to use LaTeX3 features from within LaTeX2e? Or are you suggesting that I move to using LaTeX3?

Comment: @YM_Industries LaTeX3 is at present not a stand-alone format but 'ideas' implemented as LaTeX2e packages. As such, you can happily intermix the two (certainly for things like `expl3`).

Answer (score 6):

TeX is a macro expansion language, and so there is no such thing as 'returning' a value. For an *expandable* macro, one can arrange for the expansion to take place before the result is used. In some cases, for example using `\ifdim`, that will be part of the command itself (`\ifdim` performs expansion).

The calculations performed by `fp` are not done in an expandable way (they use assignments internally). As such, to use `fp` you will need to set up your calculations a different way, putting the calculation inside the same place as the comparison. As detailed in the answer by [Runar Trollet](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/333323), you are probably better off using an expandable calculation set up such as the one in `expl3`. As the other answer covers this I won't go into it further, but I would point out that you've got a lot of whitespace in your answers (see [What is the use of percent signs (%) at the end of lines?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/7453/what-is-the-use-of-percent-signs-at-the-end-of-lines)). You can also make the comparison expandable:

```
\newcommand\clamp[3]{%
  \ifdim #1pt<#2pt
    #2%
  \else
    \ifdim #1pt>#3pt
      #3%
    \else
      #1%
    \fi
  \fi
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the tip, I'll be more careful about where I'm generating whitespace.